# permutation, equiprobability and random variable for a movie night

Tags: probability, permutations, solution-verification

here's a small question I asked myself and I would be happy to discuss it with you.

2 friends (Oscar and Jake) are organizing movie nights. Each of the 2 participant choose $n$ movies. Every night a movie will be randomly choosen and watched. every movie can only be choosen once. What is the probability that the first $n$ movies are all Jake's (or Oscar's) movies ?

Here's my attempt to solve the problem :

A movie choosen by Jake will be denoted by $J$ and a movie choosen by Oscar will be denoted by $O$. I am interested in the probability of the event :

$$ A= JJJ...JJJOOO...OOO \cup OOO...OOOJJJ...JJJ. $$

Using equiprobability, I guess the probability to be :

$$ P(A)=\frac{2}{\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}}. $$

The 2 in the nominator comes from the fact that $A$ consists of 2 events. The denominator is the total number of permutation of the $2n$ movies. Is my reasoning correct ?

Also I have a second question. I just started teaching myself some probability and statistics and I would be really happy to solve this problem using random variables. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it, is it even possible ? I guess I should use a binomial random variable, right ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are correct. Simpler would be to say you need to choose $n$ places out of $2n$ for J, so you have ${2n \choose n}$ possibilities, out of which only 2 are the ones you look for. Binomial random variable is not appropriate here (what is the "success?"). Try to solve it using the Hypergeometric random variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, it really helped me. Could you maybe help me with the hypergeometric law ? I found that it is defined by 3 parameters $(n,p,A)$ and in my case those would be $(2n,\frac{1}{2},2n)$. But I think that I'm wrong...

Comment: You have $N$ objects, $D$ of which are "special" and you choose a subset of $n$. $X~HG(N,D,n)$ is the random variable that counts how many "special" there are in the chosen set. In this example, we have $2n$ objects, $n$ of which are special ("J") and you choose $n$ movies to watch first. You want all of them to be special ("J") or non-special ("O") so the probability is $\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=n)$.

Comment: thank you ! I just managed to show that $P(X=0)+P(X=n)=\frac{2}{ {2n} \choose{n} }$.